# Using multiple HTML collapsibles

Tags: html

I am using the W3schools e[xample code](http://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_collapsible&stacked=h) for collapsible text with a button as shown here:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
  <p>Click on the button to toggle between showing and hiding content.</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible</button>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get multiple collapsible buttons to work however when I create a second button it opens the first collapsible text.

Any help would be appreciated as I only have a very limited understanding of HTML.

Comment: can you share you code so that we can point it out where you go wrong

Comment: Hello there. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide relevant codes along with your questions. Codes in external links are frowned upon here as these links might expire thus rendering the thread useless for other people later.

Comment: Can we see the code snippet? stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. And make the effort to complete the 2-minute site tour as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sample (below) may be of assistance. The original code is from the [W3Schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_collapsible&stacked=h) you referenced.

Note that the 2nd button's `data-target` references the 2nd collapsible div's id `demo2` as opposed to the first collapsible div's id `demo`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
  <p>Click on the button to toggle between showing and hiding content.</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible</button>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2">Simple collapsible 2</button>
  <div id="demo2" class="collapse">
    2nd
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, thought it was something simple :)

Comment: Perhaps you  would be kind enough to up-vote my answer?

Comment: I would, but as a new user I can't sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

To do this you need to specify a second target `id` `div` using the `data-target`.

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
  <p>Click on the button to toggle between showing and hiding content.</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible 1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2">Simple collapsible 2</button>
  <div id="demo2" class="collapse">
    collapsible 2
  </div>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse">
    Collapsible 1
  </div>
</div>
```

I've omitted the head from that example for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

Each collapsable div should have a unique id which should be linked to it's respective button's `data-target` like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#button1">Simple collapsible</button>
  <div id="button1" class="collapse">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#button2">Simple collapsible</button>
  <div id="button2" class="collapse">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
```

Note that I have assigned unique ids (#button1, #button2) to each div? That's how the button knows which div to target.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $(this).next().slideToggle(400);
});
```

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
.content {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #EAEAEA;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-toggle">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="btn">Some Text Button</div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda impedit, numquam id vero velit dolorem tempora quas? Ad possimus dolor nemo repudiandae. Facere, magnam, necessitatibus? Est, odio tempore provident in!</div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <div class="btn">Another Text</div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda impedit, numquam id vero velit dolorem tempora quas? Ad possimus dolor nemo repudiandae. Facere, magnam, necessitatibus? Est, odio tempore provident in!</div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <div class="btn">Another Button</div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda impedit, numquam id vero velit dolorem tempora quas? Ad possimus dolor nemo repudiandae. Facere, magnam, necessitatibus? Est, odio tempore provident in!</div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <div class="btn">Some Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda impedit, numquam id vero velit dolorem tempora quas? Ad possimus dolor nemo repudiandae. Facere, magnam, necessitatibus? Est, odio tempore provident in!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```